# Given Distribution Function, Calculate Probability Mass Function $P(X \ge 11500)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Say we have the distribution function
$$
F(a) = \begin{cases}
0 & 20 \\
0.02 & a < 3800\\
0.64 & a < 7200\\
0.89 & a < 12200\\
1 & a \ge 12200
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to calculate $P(X\ge 11500)$

As per my calculation  $P(X\ge 11500) = 1 - P(X < 11500)$
Which then should be $1 - 0.64 = 0.36$ yet, for some reason the correct answer is $1 - 0.89 = 0.11$

Would appreciate someone explaining this to me. Why is it that we round $a$ up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $P(X<11500)=F(11500)=0.89$, as $11500<12200$

Comment: OFCOURSE! Thanks!!